# ASP.Net MVC: How to use @Html.ValidationMessageFor in Webgrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webgrid

suppose my webgrid code look like

suppose this is my webgrid code

```
@model HelloWorldMvcApp.MainViewModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}

@{
        WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(null);
        grid.Bind(Model.Students);

    }
    @grid.GetHtml(
            tableStyle: "webgrid-table",
            headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
            footerStyle: "webgrid-footer",
            alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-row",
            selectedRowStyle: "webgrid-selected-row",
            rowStyle: "webgrid-row-style",
            mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
            firstText: "<<",
            previousText: "<",
            nextText: ">",
            lastText: ">>",
            numericLinksCount: 5,
            columns:
                grid.Columns
                (
                grid.Column(columnName: "ID", header: "ID", format: @<text>@item.ID</text>,style:"SmallCols"),
                grid.Column(columnName: "FirstName", header: "First Name", format: @<text><input type="text" id="txtFirstName" value="@item.Name" class="edit-mode" /></text>,style:"NameColWidth" ),

                //grid.Column(columnName: "StateName", header: "State Name", format: @<text>@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedState, new SelectList(Model.Students[1].States, "ID", "Name", Model.SelectedState = item.StateID), "-- Select States--", new { id = "cboState", @class = "edit-mode" })</text>,style:"NameColWidth"),

                grid.Column(columnName: "StateName", header: "State Name", format: @<text>@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedState, new SelectList(Model.Students.SelectMany(x => x.States).Where(x => x.ID == item.StateID), "ID", "Name", Model.SelectedState = item.StateID), "-- Select States--", new { id = "cboState", @class = "edit-mode" })</text>,style:"NameColWidth"),
                grid.Column(columnName: "CityName", header: "City Name", format: @<text>@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedCity, new SelectList(Model.Students.SelectMany(x => x.Cities).Where(x => x.StateID == item.StateID), "ID", "Name", Model.SelectedCity = item.CityID), "-- Select City--", new { id = "cboCity", @class = "edit-mode" })
                </text>,style:"NameColWidth")
                ))
```

now tell me how to put `@Html.ValidationMessageFor` for each textbox and dropdown ?

my full working code `https://dotnetfiddle.net/GoJeBE`

please discuss with code sample. thanks

Comment: You should just be able to add `@ValidationMessageFor()` between the `<text>` elements (adjacent the `@DropDownListFor()`) But you fiddle wont work - you don't have a form. And it wont work for the textboxes because you manually generating the html (with out the necessary `data-val-*` attributes - you need to use `@Html.TextBoxFor()`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke one request that i am new in MVC. can u please post a new view code with webgrid including Html.ValidationMessageFor. i can try but scare that i may made mistake. would u help me. thanks

Comment: I have forked your [DotNetFiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/okrNsf) and modified it to add validation for the textbox (clear the contents and click the submit button and the validation error will be shown). But have previously given you my opinion on WebGrid` and linked you to the opinion of other top MVC users - its rubbish, don't use it.

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks for your code but validation message should show in red color and control should have red border when validation fail. this is not happening. what is missing in code in your dotnet fiddle?

Comment: That's because the fiddle **you** created (I just forked it) does not have any of the relevant css.